# rxJava Observer.onNext not called second time

Tags: android-fragments, rx-java, rx-android

I am using rxJava to fetch data from the database and show it in a recyclerview. The relevant code is shown below

```
function updateUI(){
  ContactsLab contactsLab = ContactsLab.get(getActivity());
  Subscription sub = contactsLab.getContactList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .toList()
            .subscribe(onContactsReceived());
  mCompositeSubscription.add(sub);
}
```

`ContactsLab` is a singleton that returns an Observable of Contact objects.
`onContactsReceived` function is shown below

```
private Observer<List<Contact>> onContactsReceived(){
    return new Observer<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {}

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {}

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Contact> contacts) {
            if(mContactsAdapter == null) {
                mContactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mContactsAdapter);
            } else{
                mContactsAdapter.setContactList(contacts);
                mContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The `updateUI` function is called in my fragment `onResume` but the view is updated only the first time. If I come back to this fragment from any other fragment (having added more items to db), `onResume` is called, `updateUI` runs and `onContactsReceived` also runs but returns immediately without calling `onNext` or `onComplete`.

I think this has something to do with the way rxJava handles observables but no idea how to fix it (read about `defer` but couldn't understand much). Can somebody please help?

**Edit:**

The `getContactList` function look like this :

```
public rx.Observable<Contact> getContactList() {
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    ContactCursorWrapper cursorWrapper = queryContacts(null, null);
    try{
        cursorWrapper.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursorWrapper.isAfterLast()){
            contacts.add(cursorWrapper.getContact());
            cursorWrapper.moveToNext();
        }
    } finally {
        cursorWrapper.close();
    }
    return rx.Observable.from(contacts);
}
```

Basically it queries the database and maps the returned `Cursor` into my Contact class(which is a POJO). I added the `rx.Observable.from` to get an observable that was later collated using `toList` and updated into the adapter.
I used this approach avoid having to call `notifyDataSetChanged` after getting each item (and call it only once after getting all that).

What's the right approach to minimize the number of `notifyDataSetChanged` calls and also, refresh each time `onResume` is called?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling `onError()` the second time?

Comment: No, nothing gets called in the observer. Debugger shows that we reach the `onContactsReceived` function at the return statement but none of the methods in the `Observer` are called. I haven't created the `observable` myself .. using the `from` function directly, does this have something to do with this?

Comment: If you're not creating the Observable then it's quite possible that when you call `getContactList()` you're not getting a new observable every time. You're just getting the old observable which has terminated and will never emit anything after the first list of contacts. From your description it certainly sounds like that's what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observable `contactsLab.getContactList().toList()` has terminated.`toList()` collects all emissions from a source observable to a list and emits the entire list once the source Observable terminates (see the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toList())). You aren't going to observe any more emissions from it.

Comment: Ohh Thanks for pointing that out! I used the toList function to update the `adapter` (as shown) . Could you please let me know a better way to get all the observables at once and update the adapter? Would storing them one by one in `onNext` and updating the adapter in `onComplete` be the right approach?

Comment: What does your `contactsLab.getContactList()` look like?

Comment: I updated the question with relevant information. Basically looking for a way to update data from a cursor without calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter more than once per call.