# rxJava how to fetch data from sqlite and showing in recycler view

Tags: sqlite, android-recyclerview, rx-java, rx-android

Recently started using `rxJava` in one of my projects. There are several demoes out there showcasing the use of `retrofit` and its observables for display but can somebody show an example of doing this with our own database.

I tried it myself ref: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984241/rxjava-observer-onnext-not-called-second-time?noredirect=1#comment65334872_38984241)

But am unable to think of a way to properly combine all the generated object `observables` into a list that can be updated inside the adapter in one go. `toList` seems to terminate the `observable` after the first run, thus can't be used directly.

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/square/sqlbrite

Comment: using `sqlbrite` means that I won't be able to utilize the `db.insert` or `update` etc methods. only `rawQuery` is supported. Am I right?

Comment: there is a `BriteDatabase` class a wrapper for `SQLiteOpenHelper`. It has method for update/delete etc. http://square.github.io/sqlbrite/0.x/sqlbrite/index.html

Comment: @LordRaydenMK : would you want to provide a sample solution for this question (using sqlbrite maybe)? I would accept it and close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To observe changes to a `SQLite` database using `RxJava` you can use [SQLBrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite).

To query the table `users` you can use:

```
Observable<Query> users = db.createQuery("users", "SELECT * FROM users");
users.subscribe(new Action1<Query>() {
  @Override public void call(Query query) {
    Cursor cursor = query.run();
    // TODO parse data...
  }
});
```

You will also receive notifications for updates/inserts as long as you are subscribed.

The code sample is from the documentation on [github](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite).